# How do I display the same activity when clicking a notification?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am developing a music player however when I click the notification which is created, a new version of this activity is displayed and not the one displaying the currently playing song and seekbar.

The current code I'm using for the notification is

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AmplitudeMusicPlayer.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , i, 0);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)    getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    noti.setContentTitle("Now Playing")
        .setContentText(songTitle)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.default_art)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti.build());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which launch mode are you declaring for your activity?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

> The "standard" and "singleTop" modes differ from each other in just
>   one respect: Every time there's a new intent for a "standard"
>   activity, a new instance of the class is created to respond to that
>   intent. Each instance handles a single intent. Similarly, a new
>   instance of a "singleTop" activity may also be created to handle a new
>   intent. However, if the target task already has an existing instance
>   of the activity at the top of its stack, that instance will receive
>   the new intent (in an onNewIntent() call); a new instance is not
>   created. In other circumstances — for example, if an existing instance
>   of the "singleTop" activity is in the target task, but not at the top
>   of the stack, or if it's at the top of a stack, but not in the target
>   task — a new instance would be created and pushed on the stack.